Sepolia ETH needed for my DEX project
Address: 0x09e50dFec4d43B1d2b37de8F0515BC78716A2F9f
Thanks in advance for anyone helping.
Need like 0.5 Sepolia ETH.

Sent 0.5 Sepolia ETH: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x1af3c678af585efd07ec5ba932e5d534db4b398c382715312a79286c5ba903b3.
